# Apache server security and cPanel scanning?

Tags: apache, cpanel, exploit, whm, malware-detection

Is there a way (or a cPanel add-on) that will continually scan sites for exploits/malware/vulnerabilities from WHM or cPanel?

Answer (score 0):

For malware problem you can use :
http://applications.cpanel.net/anti-malware-plugin-for-whm/

For the exploits and vulnerabilities , you may use external scanners, Or you can use configServer:
http://configserver.com/cp/cxs.html